# How can I avoid AWS S3 throttling issues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

All my work to access AWS S3 is in the region: `us-east2` and the AZ is `us-east-2a`.

But I saw some throttling complaints from S3, so I am wondering if I move some of my work to another AZ like `us-east-2b`, could it mitigate the problem? ( Or it will not help since `us-east-2a` and `us-east-2b` are actually pointing to same endpoint?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The throttling is not per AZ, its for a bucket. The below quote is from the AWS [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-resolve-503-slowdown-throttling/).

> You can send 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE and 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per partitioned prefix in an S3 bucket. When you have an increased request rate to your bucket, Amazon S3 might return 503 Slow Down errors while it scales to support the request rate. This scaling process is called partitioning.
>
> To avoid or minimize 503 Slow Down responses, verify that the number of unique prefixes in your bucket supports your required transactions per second (TPS). This helps your bucket leverage the scaling and partitioning capabilities of Amazon S3. Additionally, be sure that the objects and the requests for those objects are distributed evenly across the unique prefixes. For more information, see Best Practices Design Patterns: Optimizing Amazon S3 Performance.

If possible enable exponential backoff to retry in the S3 bucket. If the application uploading to S3 is performance sensitive the suggestion would be to handoff to a background application that can upload to S3 at a later time.